# How do I protect dynamical fed style sheets in Zend Framework 1 from SQL injection?

Tags: zend-framework, sql-injection

I am working on a project in Zend Framework 1.12. I want to build a facility that will enable members to dynamically upload a VCSS stylesheet of their choice; thus enabling them to format the page in the colour of their choice. The parameters to their stylesheet is load via the URL;

i.e

```
The url could be like this:   samplewebbsite/?s=rootfolder/stylesheet
we collect it with: $this->view->stylesheet = $this->_request->getParam('stylesheet', ' );
```

The getParam() gets the distination to their style sheet. i.e: rootfolder/stylsheet.css
I then display the value on the index page i.e:

```
<link href="<?= $this->stylesheet ?>" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

My question now is this: I want to protect the getParam() from javascript/sql injection/bad code etc. How do I protect it? Should I use strip_tags() or is there a better way to protect it?

Answer (score 0):

i think i worked out how to do it; i did this; i simply used strip tags.

```
$this->view->stylesheet =  $stylesheet = strip_tags ($this->_request->getParam('s', ''));
```

i tried to use the

```
$alpha = new Zend_Filter_Alpha();
$this->view->stylesheet =  $alpha -> filter($this -> _request -> getParam('name'));
```

But i found that it was also taking out all the break lines i.e the http /:Sameplesite/Rootfolder/    became  samplesiteRootfolder

if anyone has a better solution, i would be keen to hear ( ie i would have preferred to use the filter class). but otherwise. i think that my question is pretty much answered.